# ¿Como relacionar una tabla polimorfica con una tabla intermedia de una relacion muchos a muchos?

Tags: base-de-datos, eloquent, laravel-8

tengo este diseño de una base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual tareas y usuario tiene una relaciona de muchos a muchos por lo cual necesito la tabla intermedia llamada tareas_subidas, pero necesito que tanto en la tabla tareas y en la tabla tareas_subidas se puedan almacenar archivos, por lo cual cree la tabla polimorfica archivos, pero en los modelos de laravel no se como representar esa relacion entre tareas_subidas y archivos, ya que tareas_subidas es una tabla intermedia por ell no necesito un modelo de esa tabla, entonces ¿Como represento en eloquent la relacion de archivos y tareas_subidas??

```
//modelo Usuario
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function lesson()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Lesson::class);
}

public function lessons()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lesson::class);
}
//relacion muchos a muchos con la tabla tareas
public function homeworks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(homework::class);
}

}

//modelo tareas
class homework extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $table = "homeworks";

public function teacher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
//relacion muchos a muchos con usuario
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
//relacion polimorfica con archivos
public  function files()
{
    return $this->morphMany(file::class,'filesable');
}
}

//modelo archivo
class file extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
//relacion polimorfica
public function filesable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
}
```

Comment: ¿No alcanza con almacenar esos *extras* en la tabla intermedia?, digo al final estarán identificados por las llaves forénas con las cuales estñan vinculados, de otra manera si los archivos son los mismos y los destinas para 2 tablas ¿no estarías duplicando información?

Comment: @BetaM Los Alumnos pueden subir N numero de archivos para una tarea, al igual el maestro puede usar N numero de archivos para hacer su asignación de tarea, entonces si lo almacenó en la tabla intermedia estoy obligando a que los alumnos solo puedan subir un archivo por tarea.